# Installation error: Unknown failure Android App

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have just installed the Android ADT bundle with the Eclipse IDE.

I have created a Android phone Simulator and I am trying to install and run my first application on it.

Here's what I see in the Console log

```
Android Launch!
adb is running normally.
Performing com.example.outlast.MainActivity11 activity launch
Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
Uploading Outlast.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
Installing Outlast.apk...
Installation error: Unknown failure
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!
```

The application that I am trying to install is almost blank. I have just created a project with a blank activity and I am trying to run it. It is supposed to run according to to the official Android developers page.

I dont know how to look in the logcat output.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Have you waited for the device to start up? This was happening to me because I was trying to run the application while the device was still starting up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have finally resolved my problem.

I was unable to install any application on the android phone simulator because I had not waited long enough for the Android phone to load, so Eclipse couldn't install anything on the simulator.

Comment: its still unclear...eclipse just says "Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched..." for infinity.

Comment: Yes, it can take up to 15 minutes (depending on your computer) to fully launch the phone emulator.

Answer (score 4):

Same issue might also happen if you install the application some time back and now you are trying to install from another PC or sometime same PC.

Even though you have un-installed before installing new app, System maintain some data related to application. To overcome this completly unstall the application by using abd command.

```
adb uninstall my.package.id
```

Please refer [another root cause for same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794862/failure-install-failed-update-incompatible-even-if-app-appears-to-not-be-insta). This helped me a lot after spending 5hrs of my time.

Eclipse simply says that **"Installation error: Unknown failure"** it does not give info on reason for fail in console window

To see what is the error message, install apk via adb command

```
> adb install app.apk
```

Then we can see the error message as "Failed to install app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.myapp.id do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!]"

This helps to understand the issue.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The `> adb install app.apk` tip is priceless, as it revealed a setting issue in my DUT smartphone: `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user]` => I actually needed to turn on `Install via USB` on my phone's "Developer options" (which required logging into my Mi account).

Answer (score 2):

The best way for me to solve the problem, was to open the terminal and use adb manager to restart the server. I use Mac OSX and this should also work on Windows and on Linux. Go to your sdk->platform-tools folder and use the command to type the following commands:

If you use Mac, then use ./adb instead of adb.

adb kill-server (ENTER)
adb start-server (ENTER)

extra:
use adb devices to check if there are connected devices on your computer, so that you know for sure if adb works fine or not.

After no problems detected, try to unplug your device and press on the play button for installing your app. When you see a window with no devices, then you have to plug your Android device on your computer again and select it to successfully install your app.

Comment: Thanks for Mac specific

Answer (score 1):

You need to change device(emulator) android version to as per the target version.
If still not working, then restart your emulator.

Comment: Which device(emulator) version should I use ? I have Android 4.4.2 now

Comment: Have you installed Android 4.4.2 in your AVD(emulator)

Answer (score 1):

Guys i had the same issue and used the following way :
(Windows 8 , Eclipse Luna)

1) Changing the ADB connection time out to 1000000ms
2) Use ADBhost 127.0.0.1
3) Changing Method Profiler Buffer Size to 20MB
4) Unchecking the Launcher from Snapshot at AVD Emulator Options.

And of course several restarts xD

Answer (score 1):

I am working on windows 8.1 OS and I resolved the same issue by using following steps:

1. Open the command prompt
2. Navigate till `/platform-tools` folder (`C:/Sample/sdk/platform-tools/`)
3. Type `adb KILL-SERVER` and hit enter
4. Type again `adb START-SERVER` and hit enter
5. Close the already opened eclipse and restart
6. Try executing the android application and it will works

Answer (score 0):

In Play store, click left menu - my app and game - all tab - remove your application history - rebuild app