# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE] even if app appears to not be installed

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.android

When trying to deploy my app to the Android device I am getting the following error:

```
Deployment failed because of an internal error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
```

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891848/install-failed-update-incompatible-when-i-try-to-install-compiled-trebuchet-apk) but the app is not installed. It has been removed/partially removed by Visual Studio during the attempt to deploy.

In the past I solved this by downloading the app from the google play store and then removing it from settings->Application manager. However, now i am getting the error "incompatible update" when it is trying to install it.

I tried to remove it using Titanium Backup and few other things but no luck.

**EDIT 1**

I realised (from @Motz) that I haven't mentioned that the obvious solution doesn't work. Namely, the app doesn't appear in Settings->Apps

Comment: Which version installed on your device ?

Comment: It may be happen if your app required minimum SDK version is higher to you device OS version.

Comment: Check `logcat` for additional clues when trying to install the app. There should be a log entry with more details as to why it is failing.

Comment: What version of Android your phone is?

Comment: My Android version is 4.4.2. The minimum SDK is fine because I installed the App before and because I checked it.

Comment: Another solution that works for me; configure android studio/gradle to  sign the debug version with your normal key, rather than the default debug key.

Answer (score 592, accepted):

I've seen this several times. Usually, it's due to having a signed release version on my phone, then trying to deploy the debug version on top. It gets stuck in an invalid state where it's not fully uninstalled.

The solution that works for me is to open a command prompt and type:

```
adb uninstall my.package.id
```

That usually completes the uninstall in order for me to continue development.

Comment: If you are using an android device for testing and if you install your app in another machine, and then you try to install in your machine this error will appear. This solution works.

Comment: I had installed my app thru google play store and tried to redeploy thru Visual Studio Code. To solve the problem I uninstalled the app on the device.

Comment: I'm using React Native (for Android) and yeah having a signed release version already installed was the issue. I forgot I had built a release version beforehand, and then was surprised when trying to install a debug version was giving this error.

Answer (score 84):

No need to do an `adb uninstall`, just go to your `settings->apps` and then do uninstall from there. You will see your application grayed out.

The issues usually has to do with a release vs debug version such as @Kiliman noted here.

Comment: Sorry @Motz, that was actually one of the first things I did but the app is not under apps... I edited my question now

Comment: UPDATE: When using Android 5.0 (lollipop) this now works too. The app with size 0.00KB  shows and I can then easily uninstall it.

Comment: Settings > Apps > uninstall doesn't always work. Sometimes there's issues with multiple user profiles and not being uninstalled for all users. Or the app got halfway uninstalled in a bad state. `adb uninstall` would take of those scenarios.

Comment: This is not always true. Often I have done this in the past and it has worked perfectly. But today my app was simply not there. And it wasn't at the end of the application list either (sometimes you have to uninstall for all users rather than just uninstalling for the current user). `adb uninstall` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 33):

**Uninstalling the application would be enough to avoid this problem.**

```
INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE
```

but sometimes even uninstalling the message is raised again, it occurs in Android OS 5.0 +, so this is the solution:

Go to `Settings` > `Apps` and you will find your app with the message:

> "Not installed for this user"

, we have to uninstall manually for all users with the option:

> "Uninstall for all users"

Comment: Yes, it works. After unnistall for all users, `ionic cordova run android --device` works! Tks!

Answer (score 10):

You have to make sure the application is uninstalled.

In your phone, try going to `settings/applications` and show the list of all your installed applications, then make sure the application is uninstalled for all users (in my case I had uninstalled the application but still for others).

Answer (score 7):

I usually face this issue on Android 5.0+ version devices. Since it has multi-user profiles accounts on the same devices. Every app will install as a separate instance for all users. Make sure to uninstall for all the users as below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I accidentally had two devices connected.

After removing one device, `INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE` error has gone.

Comment: Also happens if the emulator is accidentally running when you didn't expect it to

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the apk(app that you are working) from your android device and then run again.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a parameter to run, see:

```
Run --> Parameters
```

In field parameters `add -cleaninstall`

Now just run, they always will do a deep clean before install.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Samsung Device and by any chance marked your app for Samsung Knox, then you need to uninstall it from My Knox app.

Uninstalling just from General apps won't uninstall it from Knox App. It has to be done explicitly!

Comment: Ah, my man! I'd been struggling with this for months before I found this small comment in the mountain of repeated answers. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Ok uninstall the app, but we admit that the data not must be lost?
This can be resolve, upgrading versionCode and versionName and try the application in "Release" mode.

For example, this is important when we want to try the migration of our Database.
We can compare the our application on play store with actual application not release yet.

Answer (score 1):

In my case. I installed the release-version app. And after uninstall the app from my device. Thing works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Signature Mismatch your Previous Present APP and new APK

**So Please uninstall the previous app and gradlew clean and again install apk**

react-native run-android

react-native run-ios

Answer (score 1):

1. Uninstall your app from connected device(emulator or mobile)
2. got terminal into project folder `cd android`
   3  next run `./gradlew clean` it clean your build
   4  `cd..` and run below 
   5  `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 1):

the first, you must uninstall your app in emulator or device, after that you can `cd ./android` -> `./gradlew clean` then build project again (run android or ios) -> solve

Answer (score 1):

uninstall the app from emulate or smart phone and try to run again

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was getting this when switched the Minimum target version of the android and when i changed back to original one (when i created project at first).
So for that uninstalling worked. But when i changed my android version to latest i was getting it again. To fix that, i went to properties of android project and in Android manifest section, i added a **package name** e.g com.dotnetdreamer.net. If you have already a package name then you can simply rename it to something else.

Comment: I changed the "Target build version" of my application from 4.4.2 to 5.0.1. Now I cannot update latest version of my app over previously released version signed with the same key. Can you provide with any URL explaining/discussing this issue as I need to share it with my clients. I am using eclipse and have also tried to resolve this issue your way but cannot find "Android Manifest" section inside project properties. Can you please help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Delete all app files from Phone**

To automate the deletion of an app on your phone you can use the steps below. It can be very useful to delete your app and app data on a quick and clean way.

Make a textfile with this code and save it as Uninstall.sh. Go to the folder (where you've put it) of this script in the terminal and do: sh Uninstall.sh YOURNAMESPACE

Now your namespacefolder (including saved appfiles and database) will be deleted.

```
  echo "Going to platform tools $HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"
  cd $HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
  echo "uninstalling app with packagae name $1"
  ./adb uninstall $1
```

**Delete all app files from pc**

Make a textfile with this code and save it as DeleteBinObj.sh.

```
find . -iname "bin" -o -iname "obj" | xargs rm -rf
```

Go to the folder of your project where you place this script and do in the terminal: sh DeleteBinObj.sh

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone, 
I deployed my app to google play, when I uninstalled it and tried to run a debug on my device (new version) I was getting this failed update message.

I **couldn't see the app in my device** (it was already uninstalled) so I:

Installed the first version again from google play

Opened Settings/App/**App name**

Cleared the **Data**

Cleared the **Cache**

Uninstalled the app

Now you can deploy the debug version again to the device :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Ionic with Cordova via command line...

```
ionic cordova run android --prod
```

I ran into this and found that I had deleted the release version from a previous test install, but had an old debug version that was hanging out in apps drawer that I missed. I unplugged my device from the computer, opened the app drawer and used "Search apps.." to find all instances of the app to uninstall them. Then I re-plugged in the device to the computer and viola, it worked!

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will help somebody in the future but simply go to you `config.xml`, inside the `widget` tag, change the default id(`io.ionic.starter`) to your own id. Have a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) for android package naming.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the application from all users may be the correct solution, but also be sure to check the **[Secure Folder](https://www.samsung.com/uk/support/mobile-devices/what-is-the-secure-folder-and-how-do-i-use-it/)** or something like that for other devices.

I spent 2 hours of my life trying to figure out the reason for the problem (I only have one user on my personal tablet)

The reason I was unable to install the application is because I mistakenly installed the application via direct link from the "Internal Testing" to both current user and my secure folders.

When you have the Secure Folder active, the tablet name appears twice: one or these is the Secure Folder. (accidentally installed on both)

[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b5yT.png)

Answer (score -1):

One simple way is rename your package name and run again