# Can't deploy app Xamarin Correctly

Tags: c#, android, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.android

My android application is not building and deploying correctly. When starting a new instance it would launch my application to my physical mobile device and I am able to debug in Visual Studio. But now it doesn't launch the application to the mobile device and when I manually run the application it is not debugging in Visual Studio. This project has portable classes and is using Xamarin.Forms.

I did change my Build Action on the AndroidManifest.xml.

I did change my file locations to not include symbols or spaces.

Attached is what the output looks like now and does nothing afterwards.

[image: Debug Issue]

Also, at the bottom of my screen which I excluded says - "Conecting to logcat: Samsung SM-N9005..." and nothing happens.

Comment: Does the app get installed on the device?

Comment: Yes. The app does get installed on the device.

Comment: Have you updated Xamarin Studio and the Xamarin Visual Studio plugin completely? If not, update everything and then restart Visual Studio. You also may try completely uninstalling the application for the device and re-deploying. Also what kind of build options do you have turned on (LLVM Compiling, Linker, etc.) and are your running the project in DEBUG mode or another mode? Finally, you might want to turn on deployment logging: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Device_Deployment_Logs

Comment: I have updated Xamarin Studio and all plugins. LLVM is off. My Linker is "None". It is definitely set to DEBUG build. The debug mode is set to build and deploy. I can't find the deployment logging screen it seems to have changed. I did open my solution in VS 2013 and it works. It seems on VS 2015 can't connect and hook the debugger on correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Use adb to uninstall the ghost of your app

```
 adb uninstall my.package.id
```

Reference:
[Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE] even if app appears to not be installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794862/failure-install-failed-update-incompatible-even-if-app-appears-to-not-be-insta)

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens when you mix between RELEASE and DEBUG versions. You cannot update a DEBUG version with a RELEASE one and vice versa.
If you do not see your app in the applications list it's because after the failing of the UPDATE it's named with the package name, and maybe the position is different than usual.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to my previously build and checked code. What worked for me is from the emulator drop down in visual studio change to some different platform tablet if phone is selected or phone if tablet is selected.