# Visual Studio 2015 C# xamarin deploy failed without errors real device adb

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, deployment

Deploy failed without errors, I'm using oneplus one (android 5.0 - API 22) as a real device. The phone is being recognized. I am able to deploy the code with an emulator, but not with a real device.

Debugging is on and the phone is authorized.

API 18-24 is installed.

```
2>Done executing task "InstallPackageAssemblies" -- FAILED. 
2>Done building target "_Upload" in project "PolyAbi.csproj" -- FAILED. 
2>Done building project "PolyAbi.csproj" -- FAILED. 
2>Build FAILED. 
2> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

verbose build output:

part1: http://pastebin.com/cNjpex8T

part2: http://pastebin.com/7aSHDBJX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]`

Try uninstalling the previous version of the application via `adb uninstall <package name>` and then redeploying your application.

Potential Duplicate: [Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE] even if app appears to not be installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794862/failure-install-failed-update-incompatible-even-if-app-appears-to-not-be-insta)