# Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug' error in react native

Tags: android, api, react-native

I just clone this project [mao-rn-android-kit](https://github.com/maolion/mao-rn-android-kit) and debugging on android device which has `marshmallow 6.0` version but debugging failed after that i switched device which has `nougat 7.1` version and it debugged successfully.

I want to run that cloned project in my device i.e `marshmallow 6.0`. I have done lot of changes in build.gradle and other files but its not running at all and showing following error. 
[image: Error while debugging on device of <code>marshmallow 6.0</code>]

what changes should i do? in following files of cloned project

```
**********app/build.gradle**********

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
   compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1"
   compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
   compile project(':mao-rn-android-kit')
}


**********android/build.gradle**********
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
```

Yet this project's apk is not installed in my device. Also i have checked in my all installed apps and settings, switched off and on my device but also not working. I am stuck on it please help.

Comment: Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709102/package-signatures-do-not-match-the-previously-installed-version

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794862/failure-install-failed-update-incompatible-even-if-app-appears-to-not-be-insta

Comment: I found that package and i am trying to uninstall it but it showing error `Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]`