# How can I run app with device owner permissions (undeletable) in Android Studio?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, adb

I have a problem with launching the flutter app in Android Studio.
The assembly of app was by "build apk" command and then we gave it "device owner" permissions.
While starting app from Android Studio it throws an error:

```
Package install error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
Package uninstall error: Failure [DELETE_FAILED_DEVICE_POLICY_MANAGER]
Error: Uninstalling old version failed.
```

We tried to delete "device owner" permissions by "remove-device-owner"("device-admin") (We have Android version 6.0.1), but this command exists only from Android 7.

Also "factory reset" button vanished from settings.

How can I delete app from my tablet or run smoothly it from Android Studio?

**We found solution: adb shell reboot recovery -> factory reset**

Comment: are you try asb command? adb uninstall [package_name]

Comment: fig out ===>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794862/failure-install-failed-update-incompatible-even-if-app-appears-to-not-be-insta

Comment: Solution: adb shell reboot recovery  -> factory reset